# How can I sort by $elemMatch in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB database I have a collection of products. Each product contains release information in an array, e.g.

```
{
  "name" : "foo",
  "release" : [{
      "region" : "GB",
      "active" : "Y",
      "date" : ISODate("2012-03-01T00:00:00Z")
    }, {
      "region" : "US",
      "active" : "Y",
      "date" : ISODate("2012-09-01T00:00:00Z")
    }, {
      "region" : "FR",
      "active" : "N",
      "date" : ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    }]
}
```

I want to find all products that are on active release in the GB region, and sort the results by the GB release date.

I tried to do this using:

```
db.product.find(
  { "release" : { "$elemMatch" : { "region" : "GB", "active" : "Y" } } }
).sort({ "release.date" : 1 });
```

This finds the correct products, but does not sort by the release date from the matched element (instead it sorts on the minimum release date from the array).

From what I have read so far, it looks like sorting by properties of the matched element is not possible, is this correct?

Can it be done with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/), and if so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the aggregation you could run to get what you want:

```
db.release.aggregate([
         {$unwind:"$release"},
         {$match:{"release.active":"Y", "release.region":"GB"}},
         {$sort:{"release.date":1}}
])
```

This unwinds the release array, matches the documents by your criteria and sorts selected ones on release date.