# Meteor JS - Sort Collection by Array value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to figure out how you would sort a collection by value where another value is == to something else see the document below

```
{
  "_id": "zLFp8KptxzACGtAZj",
  "createdAt": "2015-05-28T21:11:57.044Z",
...
  "profile": {
    "firstname": "Nelle",
    "lastname": "Carroll",
...
    "services": [
      {
        "serviceId": "Gy7uptfk8LNWMgEQy",
        "rate": 19
      },
      {
        "serviceId": "KvFETNLK8cJ78e6gy",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "serviceId": "xwY532yxcWQ7qAjuP",
        "rate": 42
      }
    ],
}
...
}
```

Say I have a collection of about 10 users whose services contain the serviceId `xwY532yxcWQ7qAjuP` I could find them using `Meteor.users.find({ 'profile.services.serviceId' : service });` but if I wanted to sort the users by the their rate using `Meteor.users.find({ 'profile.services.serviceId' : service }, , { sort: { 'profile.services.rate' : 1 } });`  It sorts the users by who has the highest rate in any service not just `xwY532yxcWQ7qAjuP`  So how would I go about sorting by rate where serviceId === `xwY532yxcWQ7qAjuP` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly as far as I know, [this is not really possible natively on MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13880789/1439597). You can probably make it work [using the agreggate framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144857/1439597):

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Then:

```
Meteor.users.aggregate([
         {$unwind:"$profile"},
         {$unwind:"$profile.services"},
         {$match:{"profile.services.serviceId":service}},
         {$sort:{"profile.services.rate":1}}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess you cannot publish aggregations since they don't have cursors? I may have to change the way I am thinking about things and just make this part of the application non-reactive. Thank you for your time and help tho!

Comment: I don't know, [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) says `aggregate()` returns a cursor...

Comment: Interesting I guess that is something they haven't added directly to meteor or to arunodas  meteor aggregate then. [View Issue](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/issues/8)

Comment: Yep, apparently it looks a little more complicated indeed... [Good followup here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/aggregation-and-publish/3186), with good advice to look up for the [counts-by-room](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) example from the docs. I have to admit it seems to add quite some complexity